# Teradata SQL conditional joining between dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two records that look like this in TABLE1:

| KEY | RECORD_START_TS | RECORD_END_TS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-06 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-11-27 00:00:00 | 2023-08-05 23:59:59 |

I need to execute a conditional LEFT JOIN where if my date minus 1 day is equal to the ending timestamp of a record, then change the conditions of the join. I have tried the below code which throws a syntax error:

```
LEFT JOIN ON CASE
    WHEN DATE'2023-08-06' - 1 = CAST(RECORD_END_TS AS DATE) THEN DATE'2023-08-06' BETWEEN CAST(RECORD_START_TS AS DATE) AND CAST(RECORD_END_TS AS DATE)
    ELSE DATE'2023-08-06' - 1 BETWEEN CAST(RECORD_START_TS AS DATE) AND CAST(RECORD_END_TS AS DATE) END
```

I have also tried this, which grabs the record with KEY = 2, but the record I am expecting to grab is KEY = 1:

```
LEFT JOIN ON CASE
    WHEN DATE'2023-08-06' - 1 = CAST(RECORD_END_TS AS DATE) THEN DATE'2023-08-06' 
    ELSE DATE'2023-08-06' - 1 END BETWEEN CAST(RECORD_START_TS AS DATE) AND CAST(RECORD_END_TS AS DATE)
```

EDIT: My problem is a very long one, but I will do my best to explain. I have 2 tables - an order data table, and a type 2 customer activity table (this is the table I provided a fake example for).

The activity table gets new records only when the order table has activity on an order that meets criteria to make the update to the activity table, and the updates come 1 day after the order complete date.

In the data I provided, an order completed on 2023-08-05, this order generated a new record. So, KEY = 2 gets an updated RECORD_END as 2023-08-05-23:59:59, AND KEY = 1 is a brand new insert with a start time 1 day after the order completed - 2023-08-06.

In my situation, another order takes place a day later on 2023-08-06 - however, not an order with sufficient activity to create a new record in the activity table.

Now, in all these cases I need to see what activity record was active before the order, and after the order. Since the order that took place on 2023-08-06 did not generate a new activity record then the latest activity record is the match for both before and after the order is the newest record.

To check activity before the order we take the completion date (2023-08-06) - 1 day. But we need to see that if this order completed 1 day after the last record change AND there was no change created from this latest record itself, then we need the latest record.

Sorry, I know that is very confusing probably due to poor explanation, I fully understand removing the question if needed.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You are basically asking: If the requested date is one day after the end date, then the requested date must not be after the end date. This is of course never true, so you are dismissing all these rows. Please tell us in words, not code, what the rule for a match is.

Comment: I suppose `DATE'2023-08-06'` is for testing and in your query it is really a column from the other table you want to outer join the table1 rows to?

Comment: I don't see how your second query can possibly return any of the rows. You must have made a mistake when copying the data. I have not found any online platform for Teradata, but here is the query in PostgreSQL, showing that neither row matches the condition: https://dbfiddle.uk/GZApEaMO

Comment: The first query is invalid by the way, because the case expression results in a boolean and Teradata does not support a boolean data type.

Comment: I am still lost. There are activities. These activities have timestamps, but these timestamps only either contain a date with time set midnight (all start times and the latest end time) or a date with a time of 23:59:59 (all other end times). Of all these activities there is always exactly one with RECORD_END_TS = 9999-12-31. This is because there is only one latest activity at a time. Every time you add a new activity, it gets RECORD_END_TS = 9999-12-31 and you update the row that had RECORD_END_TS = 9999-12-31 before to the new activity's start date minus 1 second. Yes?

Comment: And then there are orders. As activities do not necessarily have to do with one order, you don't store any order reference in the activity table. And the orders have a completion date. Now for every order you want to find certain activities based on the activity date/time range and the order completion date. Correct? I think it would be good if you showed some sample order rows plus some sample activity rows and the expected result for these orders and activities, so we get an idea of what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first table is a, and temporal dimension is b

Then the join will be like this:

```
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b
  ON (a.your_date -1)  >= cast(b.RECORD_START_TS as date)
  AND (a.your_date -1)  < cast(b.RECORD_END_TS as date)
```

OR (including the RECORD_END_TS )

```
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b
  ON (a.your_date -1)  >= cast(b.RECORD_START_TS as date)
  AND (a.your_date -1) <= cast(b.RECORD_END_TS as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

See example

```
select *
from dates d
LEFT JOIN test t ON 
   ( (d.myDate-1)= CAST(t.RECORD_END_TS AS DATE) 
     and d.myDate BETWEEN CAST(t.RECORD_START_TS AS DATE) 
                AND CAST(t.RECORD_END_TS AS DATE)
   )
 or( (d.myDate-1) BETWEEN CAST(t.RECORD_START_TS AS DATE) 
                  AND CAST(t.RECORD_END_TS AS DATE)
   )
```